# select n points out of m points all present on x-axis such that the sum of distances from each m point to its nearest nth selected point is minimum

Tags: median

The actual question is we are given 'm' areas and 'n' atm where n<=m. We have to station these 'n' atms in these 'm' areas so that the sum of distances between the areas and their nearest atm is minimum.
eg: let there be 10 areas at x-axis at points {1,2,3,6,7,9,11,22,44,50}.So, the 5 atms should be stationed at {2,7,22,44,50} to get minimum sum of distances which is 9 since 1st area is at x=1 and its nearest atm is at x=2 ,so distance1=1 and similarly distance2=0, distance3=1, distance4=1, distance5=0, distance6=2, distance7=4, distance8=0, distance9=0, distance10=0

Comment: I may have not understood what you are trying to select, but why aren't the 5 points {1,2,3,6,7}?

Comment: How do you get that the minimum distance is $9$/  The distance from $2$ to $7$ is only $5$.  Where did you take a sum?

Comment: There is likely the germ of an interesting problem here, but the body of the Question would stand some improvement.  The problem statement should be reasonably self-contained in the body (not relying only on the title to express the setup and goal).  Also it is useful to Readers to know more about *why* the problem is interesting to you, so that responses can be shaped accordingly.

Comment: @saulspatz I have edited my question for better understanding and also realized that it can be solved using k-medoids clustering